# Ubuntu 18.04 rtl8812au stops after a few hours

Tags: drivers, kernel

I think I have too much loaded ac1200 works for a while then stops..

here is what I get ...

```
$ dmesg | grep 8812au
[   13.820591] 8812au: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   13.821569] 8812au: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   13.823738] RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.20_16317.20160108
[   14.096059] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8812au
[   33.362457] rtl8812au 1-3:1.0 wlx24050ff641bf: renamed from wlan0
```

any help 
thanks Frank